# Override bootstrap css based on variables.less variables value

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Anybody knows how to override bootstrap css based on variables.less variables value on client side. After compilation of bootstrap.less it is taking variables.less values but I want to override bootstrap.css or any custom.css.

Comment: For development I will use less files after that I will remove less files for production so  What I want whatever values I am givibg for less variable it be overrided to bootstrup,css also

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with LESS (or SASS), just import bootstrap less files and put your custom variables less after bootstrap's one:

```
// Core variables and mixins
@import "variables.less";
@import "myCustomVars.less"; // YOUR CUSTOM VARS
@import "mixins.less";


// Core CSS
@import "scaffolding.less";
ETC....
```

Comment: Where should these `@import` statements be located exactly @Hugo?

Comment: If you are using SASS / LESS I strongly recommend you to use a file in which one you just import all your CSS (also vendor's ones like bootsrap). Then you write all you imports in this one.